# Standalone installation civicrm.settings.php missing

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, standalone

I installed civicrm standalone. On setup (http://SERVER/civicrm/?lang=de_DE) I obtain in the apache log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Standalone requires the path is set for now. Set $civicrm_paths['cms.root']['path'] in civicrm.settings.php to the webroot.
BUT: Where is civicrm.settings.php located? Can't find it!
Regards, Michael "bonzius".

Comment: What cms are you on? Drupal7, Drupal10, Wordpress, Joomla?

Comment: I installed the "standalone"-Verion. No CMS.